# Jquery scroll animation plugin

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

Can you suggest same with this scroll animation using jquery? http://www.im-viadukt.ch/content/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jcarousel and need to customize this to look like the reference you mention above.